# Convex varieties that are not homogeneous

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

A projective variety $X$ is convex, if for any $f:\mathbb{P}^1 \to X$, the group $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, f^*(T_X))$ vanishes. A big group of examples of convex varieties is made of homogeneous varieties. An homogeneous variety is the quotient variety $G/P$ of a Lie group $G$ by a parabolic subgroup $P$ of it.

My question is: is there an easy example of a projective variety, possibly smooth, that is convex but that does not admit such a description?

In the lectures: http://www.math.uic.edu/~coskun/utah-notes.pdf, the author asks whether every rationally connected smooth convex projective variety must also be homogeneous, thus suggesting that it should be rather easy to find such an example in the realm of non-rationally connected varieties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course every variety containing no rational curves is convex, by default. For a less trivial example, take the product of one such variety (for example, an abelian variety) with a homogeneous variety.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I was after an example of a disconnected moduli space of genus $0$ stable maps, with target a convex variety. So as an addendum to this question, can one easily infer from what you said an example of a variety $X$ whose moduli space of genus $0$ stable maps consists of two distinct points?

Comment: Well, the space of stable maps of genus 0 to $X$ is the union of infinitely many spaces, one for each degree (once you fix a polarization on $X$). Now, in degree zero you get the space of constant maps, which is isomorphic to $X$. If there are no rational curves on $X$, this is all; otherwise, for each rational curve you get maps in infinitely many degrees. I suppose that you could rephrase your question as: if you fix a degree (or a homology class), can you have a moduli space with two components? The answer is yes, that's easy. Do you care to see examples?

Comment: Yes. More generally, where can I find examples of this kind?

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation of Angelo's first example. Consider a surface without rational curves and blow-up a finite number of distinct points. If $E$ is one of the exceptional divisors and $f \colon E \to X$ is the inclusion in the blow-up, since

$H^0(E, N_{E|X})=H^1(E, N_{E|X})=0$,

we obtain $H^1(E, f^*T_X)=H^1(E, T_E)=0$, so $X$ is convex. On the other hand, $X$ is not homogeneous, since its automorphism group does not act transitively.

**ADDED**. As remarked by mdeland, this example does not really work since we can take 
finite covers of $E$ in order to obtain curves that violate the convexity condition. 
In order to avoid this problem, we must require that the splitting type 
of the tangent bundle of $X$ over any rational curve does not contain summands of negative degree. Let us give an example where this condition is satisfied.

Let $C$ be any curve of genus $g(C) \geq 1$ and let 
$\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{O}_C \oplus \mathcal{L}$, where
$\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundle of negative degree $-e$. 
Then $X = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}) $ is a ruled surface over $C$ 
which contains a unique section $C_0$ such that 
$C_0^2 = -e$, in particular $X$ is not homogeneous.

Now let us show that $X$ is convex. Let $F \cong \mathbb{P}^1$
be any fibre of $p \colon X \to C$. We have a short exact sequence

$0 \to T_F \to (T_X)|_F \to N_F \to 0$.

Since $T_F=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}}(2)$ and $N_F=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$, 
it follows $\textrm{Ext}^1(N_F, T_F)=0$. Therefore the sequence above actually splits
and we obtain

$(T_X)|_F = \mathcal{O}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}$.

On the other hand, since $g(C) \geq 1$ the unique rational curves on $X$ are the fibres of $p$,
so every non-constant holomorphic map $f \colon \mathbb{P}^1 \to X$ is given by the inclusion 
of a fibre composed with a finite cover. If $d$ is the degree of such a cover, we obtain

$f^*T_X = \mathcal{O}(2d) \oplus \mathcal{O}$.

It follows $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, f^*T_X)=0$, so $X$ is convex. Notice that $X$ is uniruled, 
but not rationally connected.

Comment: If you take a map \PP^1 \rightarrow X which is a multiple cover of the exceptional divisor E, then you will produce a rational curve on X where the convexity condition fails.

Comment: Ops, you are right. I don't know why, I was thinking only about (generically) injective maps. I will edit the answer. 

Comment: This is nice.  By looking at the mrc fibration, conjecturally examples would all have to be of this form:  they would map to a variety with no rational curves on them and the fibers would be homogeneous spaces.  This also encompasses Angelo's examples.  (Of course, the fibration is only a rational map in general...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the related comments. It seems this would be an insightful example for proving that convex+rationally connected implies homogeneous.